# What kinds of manifolds admit concave boundary?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We can find many examples of smooth Riemannian manifolds with boundaries whose boundaries are convex. But it seems to me I know no any example of smooth Riemannian manifold with concave boundary. So my question is What kinds of smooth Riemnnian manifolds admit concave boundaries?  Do they exist? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question isn't well-formulated.  Are you starting with a ?compact/open? ?topological/smooth/PL? manifold ?with/without? boundary?   Or are you talking about starting with more structure than smoothness? 

Comment: Thank you. I mean smooth manifolds with boundaries. I edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by convexity of the boundary? It has no meaning without additional structure (e.g. a Riemannian metric or an embedding into $\mathbb R^n$).


Comment: In addition to the above remark, I would stress that there are a lot of trivial Riemannian examples: take a compact Riemannian manifold and remove a small ball.

Comment: Yes, I mean what kind of metric on a compact manifold with boundary could have a concave boundary.

Comment: I think the question is asking if $M$ is a compact smooth manifold with boundary, can you find a Riemann metric on it so that *all* non-constant curves in the boundary have geodesic curvature pointing *out* of the manifold. 

Comment:   Exactly! Dear Ryan, you know what I meant. In addition I am curious if the curvature of such a metric could be nonnegative or bounded below? 

Comment:  Sure, I think Kloeckner is right, there are many trivial Riemannian examples. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is yes and in a strong way.

Precisely, let $M$ be a compact manifold, and put *any* Riemann metric on $\partial M$ Then I claim there is a Riemann metric on $M$, extending the Riemann metric on $\partial M$ with $\partial M$ convex in the sense above -- that the geodesic curvature of boundary curves point out.  Moreover, you can do the same if you replace convex with concave.

The idea is fairly simple.  Take a collar neighbourhood of $\partial M$ in $M$.  The collar neighbourhood is diffeomorphic to $[0,1] \times \partial M$.  The idea is to pull-back the metric on $\partial M$ to $[0,1] \times \partial M$, and then linearly re-scale the metric but only in the $\partial M$ direction.  If you re-scale so that $\{t\} \times \partial M$ has its Riemann metric $(t+1)$ times the Riemann metric for $\{0\} \times \partial M$, this does the job.  You then use a partition of unity to extend the metric to all $M$.